# How to set a property of a property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a user-control as my view (named `MyView`) and it has it's data context set to an instance of my view-model (of type `MyViewModel`).
I have in my view's code-behind a read-only property for it (which is the MVVM-Light snippet) that looks like so:

```
public MyViewModel Vm
{
    get { return (MyViewModel) DataContext; }
}
```

`MyViewModel` has a property named `Title` of type string, and I want to change it through XAML because `MyView` is being used as an `ItemTemplate` for a `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:MyView /> <!-- How do I set Vm.Title property here? -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can I do this?
*or perhaps there is a better way?*

Comment: Your approach is backwards. If you already have a VM Collection, Why don't you manipulate such property in the items of that collection?

Comment: @HighCore Care to explain a bit further? I don't fully understand.

Comment: Where are your ListBox Items coming from? A collection of `MyViewModel`, right? - Then, why do you insist in altering the DATA in the View, instead of in the ViewModel itself? you seem to be misunderstanding some core concepts of MVVM

Comment: @HighCore Oh! I've tried it before but it didn't work so smoothly so some answers in SO gave me the idea that this was a better option. That wasn't correct?

Comment: Data is Data. UI is UI. UI shows the data that's exposed and provided by ViewModel and Model, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you simply make a property within your `MyView` that reflects down to the view model?

```
public string Title 
{ 
    get { return ((MyViewModel) DataContext).Title; } 
    set { ((MyViewModel) DataContext).Title = value; }
}
```

Then write:

```
<Controls:MyView Title="MyTitle" />
```

If you want to bind the title, you'll have to make it a dependency property not a regular property.